# meta tag with multiple name values

Tags: html, meta

I have the following two meta tags on my website

```
<meta name="author" content="@vanntile" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@vanntile" />
```

I know that I cannot use two **name** atributes in the same meta tag, like this:

```
<meta name="author" name="twitter:creator" content="@vanntile" />
```

My question is, is the following meta valid?

```
<meta name="author,twitter:creator" content="@vanntile" />
```

Comment: What's wrong with the two-tag setup?

Comment: Nothing wrong, maybe a bit long (but that does not matter). It is just a programming question...

Comment: It's your only option here. The method you posited is invalid.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Would you post an answer with the official documentation for meta tags?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have that to hand, but I know the syntax isn't valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [HTML5 Standard](https://developers.whatwg.org/semantics.html#attr-meta-name), the a `meta` element with a `name` attribute expresses a single metadata name-value pair, and the `name` attribute contains the name part of the pair.

While the code you suggested is not invalid, it will mean the metadata pair ("author,twitter:creator" : "@vanntile"), not both ("author" : "@vanntile") and ("twitter:creator" : "@vanntile").